# Is 'Can you make sure...?' rude?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I know that imperative *Make sure...* can be not polite. How softer is *Can you make sure...?* Can I write this to my boss?

Context: Something is blocking my work that depends on my boss, and I want to ask him to do his part so I can continue.

Can I write this?

> Can you make sure you do this by the end of the week?

Comment: How about "Please do this by the end of the week"

Answer (score 1):

No matter how much you soften it, ***make sure*** is rude addressed to your boss. You could express it differently,

> I would be grateful if you could do this by the end of the week so that we can complete the task.